# bound friend templates in SGI STL

Tags: c++, stl

I know that SGI STL is as old as myself, but I still want to figure it out.

In [stl_stack.h](https://github.com/Jameeeees/sgi-stl/blob/master/tass-sgi-stl-2.91.57-source/stl_stack.h), there is some code like this:

```
template <class T, class Sequence = Deque<T> >
class Stack {
    friend bool operator== __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS (const Stack&, const Stack&);
    friend bool operator< __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS (const Stack&, const Stack&);
protected:
    Sequence c;
};

template <class T, class Sequence>
bool operator== (const Stack<T, Sequence>& x, const Stack<T, Sequence>& y){
    return x.c == y.c;
}

template <class T, class Sequence>
bool operator< (const Stack<T, Sequence>& x, const Stack<T, Sequence>& y){
    return x.c < y.c;
}
```

In [stl_config.h](https://github.com/Jameeeees/sgi-stl/blob/master/tass-sgi-stl-2.91.57-source/stl_config.h), `__STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS` is defined like this:

```
# ifdef __STL_CLASS_PARTIAL_SPECIALIZATION
#   define __STL_TEMPLATE_NULL template<>
# else
#   define __STL_TEMPLATE_NULL
# endif
```

but when I tried to compile it with G++ 4.9.2, the compilers said this:

```
In file included from stack.cpp:1:0:
stack.h:13:22: error: declaration of ‘operator==’ as non-function
  friend bool operator== __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS (const Stack&, const Stack&);
                      ^
stack.h:13:22: error: expected ‘;’ at end of member declaration
In file included from iterator.h:3:0,
                 from deque.h:6,
                 from stack.h:5,
                 from stack.cpp:1:
stl_config.h:111:31: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
 # define __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS <>
                               ^
stack.h:13:25: note: in expansion of macro ‘__STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS’
  friend bool operator== __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS (const Stack&, const Stack&);
```

I don't know why the exactly same code can't compile on my computer, is this code illegal code now or something?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: You might be looking for `#   define __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS <>`, line 192.

Comment: The code may be no longer conformant, but if the question is more around what the syntax is for be-friending templates, you could look here; http://stackoverflow.com/a/35891188/3747990

Comment: I am sure ```# define __STL_NULL_TMPL_ARGS <>``` is included. @Potatoswatter

Comment: @Pyjamas I mean you copy-pasted the definition of `__STL_TEMPLATE_NULL` which is unrelated.

Comment: @Niall Thank you! I added some forward declaration, and it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stl_stack.h` has an error which must have gone under the radar of contemporary compilers. It's illegal to mention `operator== <>` before `operator==` has been declared as a template.

To fix this, declare `operator==` before the definition of `stack`. But if you're declaring it at that point, you might as well define it. And the declaration will require a forward declaration of `stack`:

```
template <class T, class Sequence>
class stack; // Forward declare for sake of operator== declaration.

template <class T, class Sequence>
bool operator==(const stack<T, Sequence>& x, const stack<T, Sequence>& y) {
  return x.c == y.c;
}

#ifndef __STL_LIMITED_DEFAULT_TEMPLATES
template <class T, class Sequence = deque<T> >
#else
…
```

(Of course, having added the `operator==` definition to the top, you'll remove it from the bottom.)